# flask-CORS partially fails when making requests with axios in React

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, cors, flask-cors

I am using React for the front-end running on 'http://localhost:3000' and Flask for the backend running on http://127.0.0.1:5000.
I am running into the following error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/manager/personnel' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
I am using the following code to set up CORS:

```
cors = CORS(origins=['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000','http://localhost:5000'])
...

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    cors.init_app(app)
```

I also tried using CORS at the blueprint level unsuccessfully.
What is most surprising is that some requests to the backend still succeed.